# NetSuite WYSIWYG Preview no longer working

Tags: netsuite, wysiwyg, pdfhtml

I am creating a custom advanced PDF/HTML template. I switched between WYSIWYG editor and source code editor and maybe saved. So now my template no longer shows up properly when try to preview it.

1. Does anyone know how I can fix this so that the preview shows my
   changes as I make them?
2. Can anyone suggest what I can use going
   forward so this doesn't happen to me again (ex: an IDE where I can
   preview before moving code into NetSuite)?
3. Also, I did not save my source code before editing it since I thought NS was just making a
   copy of the code in the custom template. So if anyone knows where I can get a copy of the
   original source code for the original template that may help as well.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: They do provide an integration with WebStorm / IntelliJ that lets you download various NetSuite files/objects so they can be put in version control. Used in myself when I worked with NetSuite. Also Sandbox/Production accounts might have an older version depending on which environment you are working in and when the Sandbox was last refreshed.

Comment: Brian thank you for the quick response. I was working in a sandbox to make my advanced PDF/HTML template customizations. Unfortunately that somehow broke the preview in all instances of NS for that one template, Even deleting the custom template and trying to create a new custom template doesn't work when I try to preview it. I didn't think it was possible to actually effect the other instances from sandbox, but NS has proven me wrong.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your third question, I am assuming you started from one of the standard Advanced PDF/HTML templates and hit customize?  If so, you should be able to get the source code for the standard template the same way: hit customize, then switch to source code view.

Remember that NetSuite does warn you that once you switch to source code, switching back may not work for that template.  I generally switch to source code mode and do all my work in that mode.  I use a sample transaction to preview the changes, or hit the "preview" button in the template editor.

I am not aware of any editor that will let you preview this in WYSIWYG mode, but I use Visual Studio Code to edit the templates.  They now also have a SuiteCloud integration plug in, but it's a bit buggy.  WebStorm is probably ok, but is not free.  There is also Eclipse which is free, but they are deprecating its NetSuite plug in, and the upload to account functions don't work anymore because of the security enhancement to authentication.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you Pierre, for trying to help. I agree, I should be able to get the original preview and source code from the standard template. However, even upon returning to the standard template and the source code is there, but the preview still does not work. I did delete my custom template and try the standard template and the preview is still broken. So it seems like my custom template changed the standard template somehow, NetSuite documentation doesn't cover this and I am not sure they even know it can happen.

Comment: That is very odd, @Simon.  There is nothing of which I am aware that can change the source code for a standard template—these should be "locked": no edit button, only customize.  Are you able to preview other templates?  Do you have a Sandbox account?  If so, have you tried this there?

Comment: Yes it is very odd @PierrePlourde, that is why the documentation doesn't cover it and so far no one has been able to help me. The preview is broken in Sandbox and Production and it is only on that template. The source code is there, but the preview does not fully generate from it. Somehow the link was broken, I think if I could get a copy of the code with a pasted copy of the WYSIWAG template copied to the account it would fix it, but there is no place to get that.